# Score calculation for query of size = 0

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using queries with `size` param set to `0` for getting fast counts without fetching docs data.

```
{
  "query": {
    <query_body>
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Am I right with my assumption that the score calculation is not being performed in such cases?

I have some doubts. E.g. when I am querying with `sort` another than the `_score` I get `"max_score": null` which confirms that the score is not being calculated in that case. But in this current case (`"size": 0`) I get `"max_score": 0` that looks more like the score is being calculated, but no docs are returned, so the `max_score` is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the answers you are looking for, but still: It could well be that the score is still calculated. In your case I would use another solution. You should use the search type of a query:

```
?search_type=count
```

More information can be found here:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#search-request-search-type

Comment: But I'm still interested in the case described above as it allows me to produce simpler queries builder's code - when it is needed to get only count (without fetching docs) - simply add `"size": 0` to the query, and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `size: 1` and `_source: false` to limit the size of the return results but you need to have at least `size: 1` to have the `max_score` appear. By default it should be sorting by score so the top return result will have the highest score.

Here is what I did:

```json
{
  "size": 1,
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    <query_body>
  }
}
```

Which returns a result like this:

```json
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.37365946,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "examples",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "9deff2cf-4e9b-46a9-8e56-2d97d1b2535a",
        "_score" : 0.37365946
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So you get *one hit* which lacks its `_source` field which means that this payload should always be this size exactly regardless of your documents.